# Options to simulate revoking a SAS token azure servicebus

Tags: azure, message-queue, servicebus

I wanted to get some advice on a solution I have implemented to manage the inability to revoke a token in ServiceBus.

The issues that we have is when we are required to remove access for a installed field device and how to best achieve this.  The inability to revoke a token makes this challenging.

**The issue:**
Our systems will place in the field hardware that will access various queue's, topics and relays.  If this hardware fell into the wrong hands it would be possible for someone to reverse engineer the code and obtain the token's that gives them access to these queue's and topics.  Once they had this it would not be difficult to create a dos attack on our systems.

Ideally - if we detected this event, we could recover by quickly blocking access - but this is not that straight forward when a token can't be revoked. Waiting for a token to time out would not be an acceptable solution.

It is recommended that we create a SAS token for client applications, and where possible we make the token security access as specific as possible (path, listen and send permissions). revoking the shared access policy (SAP) would not be an option as this would also impact other token's that remain valid as there is only a very limited number of SAP therefore they must be shared.

ServiceBus queue's where they only listen on the hardware for new messages are not a real concern, as a dos attack on a listener I'm not sure is a concern, as you can delete the queue or topic subscription without impacting other hardware, its more when the hardware sends to a queue that is also accessible by other hardware.  We have a number of queue's that for example send logging data back to our systems.  All installed hardware was to use the same queue, so we have many senders and one receiver.

This means that it is not possible to delete the queue to fix the dos attack, as the queue is used by other hardware.

The Fix:
To fix this issue - we implemented a forwarding queue.  Now each hardware has it's own specific queue unique to the hardware and this queue forwards directly onto the common logging queue.  This means that when something goes wrong, we can delete the hardware specific queue without impacting other hardware.

This has a slightly more complex setup, and also increases the costs of the azure services as messages are duplicated I believe.  it also means creating many more queue's.  In the original system we had one queue for all hardware, now we have a unique queue for each hardware.

Is this a recommended solution to the security issue I have detailed above?  Before I go and implement this fully I would interested in how others have solved this issue?

Comment: I think this question would be better at http://security.stackexchange.com/